# Screen divider / border width and color

Tags: linux, terminal, gnu-screen

In GNU screen, using a horizontal / vertical split, how do you set the color and width of the divider between the splits? I want to make them thin and darker so they don't stand out as much.

There is an image of what I mean :
[image]

I suppose one is a divider and the other is a statusline. I'd like both to go to a more neutral tone.

I'm using the [dev version](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/screen.git) of GNU Screen, configured with `--enable-colors256`. This has vertical split built in as well as sane behaviour with Vim when `:defbce= 'on'.`

Comment: `:rendition so kb` changes the colours to black and blue.

Comment: My solution was to use [tmux](http://tmux.sourceforge.net/) instead.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

@evilsoup: As you want a "distraction-free writing environment", you probably don't want *any* infos in the windows caption -- nothing but the default beckground color of your terminal, so use

```
caption string "%{= dd} "
```

This sets the back- and foreground color to default (`d`) and displays nothing (`" "`).

To get rid of the vertical bars, use the option proposed by @aaren:

```
rendition so "="
```

but do neither set the fore- nor the background color. This command works with `screen 4.01.00devel`, but with earlier (even `<= 4.00`) or non-devel versions you might need to use `sorendition "="` instead.

When you add these lines to the screen config files as proposed by [Stephane Chazelas on UL](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/85440) you should be fine:

[image]

Comment: Btw. [Q10](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Q10_(text_editor)) sound as if designed for you -- _but_ it's Windows only `:(`.

Comment: This is so close I can taste it -- this works perfectly with a black background, but I use gnome-terminal with a dark purple background. Is it possible to specify an arbitrary colour? With HTML color codes or something similar.

Comment: @evilsoup: I don't think you can specify a color by an arbitrary RGB value (even 256 colors are [not straightforward](http://web.archive.org/web/20130313011037/http://www.frexx.de/xterm-256-notes/). But I improved my answer in that way, that screen doesn't change the color _at all_, which works fine with a white or black xterm (I cannot test with gnome-terminal), so I hope that is working for you, too.

Comment: The only caveat is that I have to use `sorendition` rather than `rendition so` (different versions of screen, maybe?) but apart from that it now works perfectly, thank you & here are your 50 reputation points. EDIT: uh, it's not letting me award the bounty yet :/ but in 19 hours time it's yours.

Comment: @evilsoup: Glad to hear and thanks for the points `:)` My man page says that _sorendition (...) is deprecated. See "rendition so" instead._, so perhaps you have some older version?!

Comment: I'm using version 4.00.03jw4, which is dated 2-May-06, so it probably is an outdated version (which is odd as the Ubuntu repos aren't normally that out-of-date). The manpages contain no mention of 'rendition so', and when I tried that in my .screenrc it threw up an error and just gave me the default white columns. Could you maybe make a note of this in your answer? 'Older versions of screen may require the syntax `sorendition "="` instead' or something like that.

Comment: @evilsoup: I added a note about that, but this is really weird, my version is `Screen version 4.01.00devel (GNU) 2-May-06`, which is as old as yours. So perhaps the _devel_ does matter?! (Btw. even today's git version identifies as `Screen version 4.01.00devel (GNUc2cd059) 2-May-06`...)

Answer (score 5):

You can easily change statusline (the horizontal one) colors, by changing your **caption string**, in your `~/.screenrc`. Given your screenshot, it looks like you are using the default one, so you may need to add in your `~/.screenrc`:

```
caption always "my caption string"
```

You can replace `always` with `splitonly`, depending on whether you want it to always show or only if window is split, and you can customize the caption string using the escape codes listed in [screen manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/screen/manual/html_node/String-Escapes.html). As an example, putting `%{= kw}` at the beginning of it will change colors to white text on black background.

You can also find lots of others caption strings over the Internet, there are a lot of `.screenrc` findable with Google. I can give you the caption string I use, it shows user name, a nice list of screen windows, date, time, and system load, all these on a black background with not too bright colors.

```
caption always "%{= g}[ %{G}${USER}@%H%{g} ][%= %{= w}%?%-Lw%?%{r}(%{W}%n*%f %t%?(%u)%?%{r})%{w}%?%+Lw%?%?%= %{g}][%{B} %d/%m %{W}%c:%s %{g}][%{Y}%l%{g}]%{=b C}%{W}"
```

Yes I know, the code is quite horrible, but with the screen documentation you should be able to adapt it or create a caption screen that matches your needs.

**Concerning the vertical separators:** I'm sorry I don't know how they will behave. Maybe they'll take the caption background color. I couldn't find documentation about it and I couldn't try it myself: the version of screen you are using dies miserably on my system with a `screen caught signal 11` ...

Answer (score 1):

For horizontal line I have used,

> caption string "%{03} "

and vertical lines I have used

> rendition so =00

The result looks like this.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here is what worked for me.

For some reason without the `r` in the `rendition so` line I was getting no line at all. I just started playing around with the attributes from the `man` page until I got what I wanted. I didn't want to remove the vertical line completely, just change its color.

```
caption string "%{03}     # remove bottom line

rendition so "=rb %{00}"  # make dividing bar bold black
```